# CNN testing performance almost 100%

Tags: matlab

Designed a CNN to detect motor movements from EEG.

Input Size (EEG data): 18x64 - 18 electrodes and 64 samples per epoch.

```
      convlayer1; (10 filters of size 1x4)
      reluLayer();
      maxPooling2dLayer([1,2],'Stride',[1 2])
      dropoutLayer(0.1);
      convlayer2; (20 filters of size 4x1)
      reluLayer();
      maxPooling2dLayer([2,1],'Stride',[2 1])
      dropoutLayer(0.1);
      fullyConnectedLayer(2);
      dropoutLayer(0.2);
      softmaxLayer();
      classificationLayer()];
```

Data from 8 subjects. Trained the network using 7 subjects and tested it using the left out subject. Did the same for all 8 subjects (basically - LOOM). Training accuracy was 96-98% and so was validation accuracy. For some subjects, the testing accuracy was 100% and for few others, it was 98-99%. Is this a case of overfitting or this result is reliable?

Thanks for your time and help.
Venkat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If testing performance is better than it's not the issue of overfitting. Overfitting avoids generalization but if your model is performing well on test data which means it is working on some unseen data and generalized well.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I asked this question because ML models like SVM and LDA were not able to achieve such results and when CNN did so, there few doubts as to whether it is actually performing or giving good result just by some thresholding or overfitting. Thanks once again.